# Set of permanents over binary square matrices

Tags: co.combinatorics

I am interested in the collection of possible values for permanents over square binary matrices. Consider $n \times n$ 0-1 matrices. The possible permanents for $n=1$ are $\{0,1\}$. For $n=2$ the possible permanents are $\{0,1,2\}$, and for $n=3$ the permanents are $\{0,1,2,3,4,6\}$. Note that $5$ is missing for $n=3$.

Let $p(n)$ denote the set of permanents for $n \times n$ binary matrices, and let $$p(\mathbb{N}) = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} p(n)$$ We can show at least that $n! \in p(\mathbb{N})$ for all $n$ and that $p(\mathbb{N})$ is closed under products.

Is this set $p(\mathbb{N})$ well understood? A pointer would be welcome. If $\mathbb{N} \subset p(\mathbb{N})$, a construction proof would be appreciated. It is not clear how to extend the trivial rectangular matrix with permanent $k$ to a square matrix.

The following related integer sequence counts distinct permanents: http://oeis.org/A087983

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That set consists of all natural numbers. Consider the $n\times n$-matrix $A=(a_{ij})$ where all numbers on the diagonal, first row and first column are equal to 1, all the other entries are 0. Then the permanent of that matrix is $n$. Indeed, each non-zero summand in the definition of permanent should start with some $a_{1,i}$. Then the $i$-th factor of that product, $i > 1$,  cannot be $a_{i,i}$. It must then be $a_{i,1}$. Hence all the other factors in that product are from the diagonal. Therefore exactly one non-zero summand in the permanent contains $a_{1,i}$, for every $i=1,...,n$. So the permanent contains exactly $n$ non-zero summands, and is equal to $n$.

Comment: I guess describing the set of permanents for matrices of a specific size could be more involved?

Comment: Will Orrick has enhanced his  his maxdet.indiana.edu site to contain information on the determinant spectrum problem as well as maximum determinant for order n 0-1 matrices.  Perhaps he can be encouraged to add permanent spectrum info as well.  Gerhard "Ask Me About Binary Matrices" Paseman, 2012.05.12

Comment: @Mariano: certainly. For example it would be interesting, I think, to understand the function $n(k)$ - the minimal size of a matrix with permanent $k$. I only showed that $n(k)\le k$ but it may be much smaller than $k$.

Comment: or the function $l(n)$ which is the smallest number which is NOT a permanent of a $n\times n$-matrix. 

Comment: Sequence $l(n)$ is A089477 in the Encyclopedia. 

Comment: I like the example of the matrix with permanent value of n.  Another calculation breaks it into the permanent of the order n-1 version and another which is easily calculated to have value 1.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.05.12

Comment: Well, all *whole* numbers (clearly the permanent may vanish, and it can surely not be negative).

Comment: @Noam: In some countries the list of natural numbers starts with 0 (I was very surprised to find it out when I first taught "Introduction to number theory" in the US). 

Comment: In fact the matter is even more complicated: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number

Comment: Whether or not $0$ is conventionally included among the "natural numbers", it's not covered by your construction.  Well, you might allow $n=0$ and argue that a $0 \times 0$ matrix has zero permanent even though its determinant is $1$.  But there's no need for that because for any $n>0$ the zero $n\times n$ matrix has zero permanent.

Comment: @Noam: I also did not mention that permanents of these matrices are non-negative. I tend not to mention trivial things in MO answers.